# Refreshing Pagination in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm having a strange issue that's only arising in my dataTable in select environments. I've written a function that allows the user to delete a row, then if it's the last row on that particular page, reload the Table and send the user to the 'new' last page.

However, on some servers, it's not working properly -- I think it has to do with the fact that with after using fnClearTable and fnDraw, the pagination of the table still holds the last 'empty' page.

Here's the function I'm working with now:

```
function fnDelete(elem) {

if (selected.length > 0) {
var c;
c = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected Agency?");
if (c) {
    var deleteURL = urlstr.substring(0, urlstr.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "delete.do";
    deleteRecord(deleteURL, selected[0]);

    if ($(".tableViewer tbody tr:visible").length === 1) {
    oTable.fnClearTable();
    oTable.fnDraw();
    oTable.fnPageChange("last");

}}}}
```

In addition, here's my delet function.

```
function deleteRecord(deleteURL, iid){
    var didDelete = false;
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: deleteURL,
            dataType:"html",
            data:"recordID="+iid,
            async : false,
            success:function(response){
                didDelete = true;
                oTable.fnDraw(true);
                selected = [];
                selectedRecord = [];
                enableButtons(selected);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                <%-- is the message in a range we can handle? --%>
                if ((xhr.status >=400) && (xhr.status < 500)) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    alert('<spring:message arguments="" text="Internal Server Error" code="ajax.internal.server.error"/>');
                }
            }   
        });

    return didDelete;
}
```

Again, this issue is only coming up on certain computers. Can anyone help?

Also, here's the configuration for my DataTable::

```
oTable = $('#${tableName}_grid').dataTable({
        bDestroy: true,
        bSort: true,
        bFilter: true,
        bJQueryUI: true,
        bProcessing: true,
        bAutoWidth: true,
        bInfo: true,
        bLengthChange: true,
        iDisplayLength: ${sessionScope.displayLength},
        sPaginationType: 'full_numbers',
        bServerSide: true,
        sAjaxSource: "<c:url value='${dataUrl}'/>",
        aaSorting: [<c:forEach items="${sortInfo}" var="oneSort">    [${oneSort.columnIndex},'${oneSort.ascending ? "asc":"desc"}']</c:forEach>],
        aoColumns: [
            <c:forEach items="${columns}" var="curCol" varStatus="colLoop">
                {sName: '${curCol.fieldName}', bSortable: ${curCol.sortable}, bSearchable: false, sTitle: "<c:out value='${curCol.title}'/>", sType: '${curCol.displayType}', bVisible:${curCol.visible}, vdbType:'${curCol.vdbType}', sClass:'${curCol.displayType}'}${colLoop.last ? '' : ','}
            </c:forEach>
            ],
            aoColumnDefs:[{sClass:"color_col", aTargets:['color']}],

            fnRowCallback: function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                $('#${tableName}_grid tbody tr').each( function () {
                    if ($.inArray(aData[0], selected)!=-1) {
                        $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                    }
                });
                return nRow;
            },
            fnInfoCallback: function( oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre ) {

if(myPos>=iStart && myPos<=iEnd){
    //alert(myPos+" visible")
}else{
    selected = [];
    selected = [];
    selectedRecord = [];
    $('tr').removeClass('row_selected');
    enableButtons(selected);
}

},
            fnDrawCallback: function ( oSettings ) {



                $('#${tableName}_grid tbody tr').each( function () {
                    var iPos = myPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                    if (iPos!=null) {
                        var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
                        if ($.inArray(aData[0], selected)!=-1) {
                            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                        }
                    }
                    var htxt = '';
                    $(this).find('.color').filter(function(i,tdata){
                        htxt = '';
                        htxt = '#'+($(tdata).text());
                        return true;
                     }).css("background",htxt);
                    $(this).dblclick( function(){
                        var iPos = myPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
                        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(iPos);
                        var iId = aData[0];
                        selected = [];
                        selectedRecord = [];
                        selected.push(iId);
                        selectedRecord.push(aData);
                        $('tr').removeClass('row_selected');
                        $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                        enableButtons(selected);
                        <%-- in case there is no edit button or its enablement is more complex,
                        // click the button instead of assuming it will call fnEdit.
                        // Do first() because jQuery is returning the same element multiple times.--%>
                        $(".${tableName}_bttns > span.edit-doubleclick:not(.disabld)").first().click();
                    });
                    $(this).click( function () {
                    var iPos = myPos =  oTable.fnGetPosition(this);<%-- row index on_this_page --%>
                        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(iPos);
                        var iId = aData[0];
                        var is_in_array = $.inArray(iId, selected);
<%-- alert("iPos: " + iPos + "\nData: " + aData + "\niId: " + iId + "\nselected: " + selected + "\nis_in_array: " + is_in_array); --%>
                        selected = [];
                        selectedRecord = [];
                        if (is_in_array==-1) {                              
                            selected.push(iId);
                            selected.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
                            selectedRecord.push(aData);
                            selectedRecord.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]});
                        }
                        else {
                            selected = $.grep(selected, function(value) {
                                return value != iId;
                            });
                            selectedRecord = $.grep(selectedRecord, function(value) {
                                return value != aData;
                            });
                        }
                        if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
                            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#${tableName}_grid tr').removeClass('row_selected');
                            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                        }
                        enableButtons(selectedRecord);
                    });
                });
            } ,
            "sDom": '<"H"lTfr>t<"F"ip>',
            "oTableTools":{
                "aButtons":[ { 
                    "sExtends":"print", 
                    "bShowAll": true,
                    "sInfo": printmsg,
                    "sButtonClass":"ui-icon fg-button ui-button edit-print DTTT_button_print",
                    "sButtonClassHover":"ui-icon fg-button ui-button edit-print DTTT_button_print"
                } ] }
        });
        $('#${tableName}_grid_filter input').attr("maxlength", "255").attr("size", "35");

        $('#${tableName}_grid').ready(function(){

            $(".DTTT_containerc").remove();

            BuildToolBarButtons();

           var tt;
           $(".DTTT_containerc").each(function(){
                tt = $(this).find("#Print").attr("title");
                $(this).find("#Print").remove();  
                $(this).find(".DTTT_container").remove();  
                }
            );

            $(".DTTT_container > button").attr("title",tt).css("border","1px solid #9597A3").removeClass("ui-state-default");    
            $(".DTTT_containerc").append($(".DTTT_container").removeAttr("style"));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please add the configuration for your datatable to the post

Comment: Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd write a response to help others to show how I fixed it.

@Gavin was correct in that it was in the wrong place -- I moved the function in question to the sucess callback in AJAX. However, to fix it fully, I had to 'premptively' read what page the deletion was happening on (using fn.PageChange plugin), subtract 1 (bc DataTables is zero-based) and send the user there.

Hope this helps anyone! @Gavin, thank you for your help and for leading me int he right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Your datatable is configured to load data using ajax. This means that any action against the data happens asynchronously. Specifically, the fnDraw() function allows control to go to the statement where you change the page page before the new data is back from the server. You should move the logic that takes you to the last page to the fnDrawCallback. I believe that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep on the same page after the table refreshed. you need to use the following snippet to keep your pagination same after refreshing datatable.   just copy paste following js code on a separate file and hook it with your current page.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnStandingRedraw = function(oSettings) {

   if(oSettings.oFeatures.bServerSide === false){
      var before = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
      oSettings.oApi._fnReDraw(oSettings);       
      oSettings._iDisplayStart = before;
      oSettings.oApi._fnCalculateEnd(oSettings);
   } 
    oSettings.oApi._fnDraw(oSettings);
};
```

and now, you might be used the "fnDraw" to refresh the dataTable.  So now, instead of that code. change it like this.

```
oTable1.fnStandingRedraw();
```

Now, your dataTable will keep the same page after refreshing it.